# GCC problem with static_cast<std::u16string>

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

## Summary

I have a class to which I've added a typecast operator to convert to `std::u16string`. The signature of this operator looks as follows:

```
operator const std::u16string() const;
```

In my .cpp file, I try converting an object of my class's type to `std::u16string` as follows:

```
std::u16string sUTF16Password = static_cast<std::u16string>(Password_);
```

On Visual Studio 2017, this works just fine. However, GCC 6.3 on my Raspberry Pi gives the following error at compile time:

```
error :  call of overloaded 'basic_string(MyClass&)' is ambiguous
```

What is the right way to write this typecast? Searching on Google brings a lot of hits for character encoding conversions, but that's not my problem here. I don't understand why the `basic_string` constructor is being called here despite using `static_cast`.

## Full example

Here's a minimal example. Compiling it with `g++ main.cpp` fails on my Raspberry Pi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::u16string Str;
    public:
        MyClass() { Str = u"abcd"; }
        operator const char16_t*() const { return Str.c_str(); }
        operator std::u16string() const { return Str; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass Tester;
    std::u16string TestStr = static_cast<std::u16string>(Tester);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < TestStr.size(); idx++)
        std::cout << idx << ": " << TestStr[idx] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of `gcc --version` is `gcc (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516`.

The full output from `g++ main.cpp` is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:61: error: call of overloaded ‘basic_string(MyClass&)’ is ambiguous
  std::u16string TestStr = static_cast<std::u16string>(Tester);
                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:476:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_
CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]
       basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:454:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&
) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:397:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_st
ring<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]
       basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I remove the typecast to `const char16_t*` this example compiles just fine. I still don't understand why having both typecasts is a problem.

Comment: Oh by the way, returning anything by `const` value is kind of useless, as the caller might still store the value in a non-const variable.

Comment: Just tried without the first const, i.e. `operator std::u16string() const`, but that makes no difference to the error.

Comment: The reason for the error is that `basic_string` has a constructor that takes a `CharT*`, and therefore `std::u16string` is constructible from a `char16_t const*`. Therefore, the compiler cannot figure which of the two operators should be invoked.

Comment: @MariusBancila so is VC++ (which doesn't complain) breaking the C++ standard?

Comment: It does complain; at least VC++ 2017. Running your sample results in error `C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'MyClass' to 'std::u16string'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`

Comment: Interesting that VC++ 2017 doesn't complain in my main code. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile as C++14 (or earlier), you'll get this ambiguous call, because `std::u16string(char16_t*)` participates in the overload resolution (via `MyClass::operator const char16_t*()`) as well as `MyClass::operator std::u16string()` that would *appear* to be a better match.

This can be overcome in several ways:

- Compile as C++17 (or later) with GCC 7 or later (sadly, this doesn't help with GCC 6).
- Remove `operator const char16_t*()`.
- Add `explicit` to `operator const char16_t*()` (or to both conversion operators).